# PHP Framework with full jQuery integration?

Tags: php, jquery, frameworks

i'm tired of reinventing the wheel on PHP and loving jQuery to death so which framework fits my needs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/jquery-helper

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.html

http://qcu.be/

Comment: oh thanks! but i'm waiting for personal experiences!

Answer (score 12):

[Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/) is a **PHP UI framework**, which comes with Object-Oriented User Interface.  Pure HTML is produced when objects are rendered recursively. jQuery and jQuery UI widgets are used to **enhance** the output and implement AJAX. Here is a simple code snippet:

```
class page_users extends Page {
    function page_index(){

        $crud=$this->add('CRUD');
        $crud->setModel('User',null,array('id','email','name','status'));
        if($crud->grid){
            $crud->grid->addColumn('expander','more','More...');
        }
    }
    function page_more(){
        $tt=$this->add('Tabs');
        $tabs=$this->add('Tabs');
        $tab=$tt->addTab('BasicInfo');
        $tab->add('MVCForm')->setModel('User')->loadData($_GET['id']);

        $tabs->addTabURL('../password','Password');
        $tabs->addTabURL('../activity','Activity');
        $tabs->addTabURL('../engage','Engage');
    }
}
```

Interface is based on jQuery UI CSS Framework and therefore can be themed using Themeroller. Interaction with HTML, JS or AJAX is handled by Agile Toolkit but can be enhanced or replaced by developer. Above code **alone** will produce this:

[image: agile toolkit screenshot]

The object structure is well-designed and can be used in major web projects. Agile Toolkit is available under OpenSource license.

See also: [atk4](/questions/tagged/atk4)

I'm [one of the authors](http://agiletoolkit.org/about/authors) of this wonderful toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

[QCubed](http://qcu.be) has been written from the ground-up with jQuery as a backing component for ALL client-side interactions. It has server-side PHP wrappers for all jQuery controls.

Answer (score 3):

The Yii framework is written around jQuery and include Zii, a jQuery UI based interface generator. It's blazingly fast and very complete.

http://www.yiiframework.com/

Answer (score 2):

QCubed. I use QCubed. All JQuery UI and Controls can be created with PHP. Plus, making things go from full page reload to ajax or even Javascript is a piece of cake. Its simply lovely.

May be other frameworks exist and do great work but QCubed was simply too irresistible to me. Look into its 'codegen' feature. :)

Answer (score 1):

Drupal also use jQuery. Depending on what kind of development you do, you may find drupal to be a nice tool, it is not just a framework but also a full grown CMS, which enables you to do really rapid development. You might however feel more in control with a framework such as the Zend framework, cakePHP or codeIgniter. 
[www.drupal.org](http://www.drupal.org)

Answer (score 1):

Silverstripe the CMS has an included MVC framework called Sapphire, tight integration with the CMS and also JQuery out of the box.

http://silverstripe.org/

Answer (score 1):

I am using [QCubed](http://qcu.be) right now on a project, and it has made things move much faster than trying to integrate jQuery into my project myself.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that Drupal is strong and good if we can simply use the contrib modules as is, and have to do less theme work. When it comes to Larger projects, Drupal means much work and less control, and for small tasks it often involves time consumption to disable the too many things it has. The other thing is that Drupal isn't that user friendly for non-technical users. I personally like Drupal alot, but when I think of the time it sometimes take to do small small things, and the lack of control we have on it (although its quite flexible but it increases time in order to do lot of form alterations for example to achieve something), I wish there is another easy way out.

Specially when it comes to theming of drupal, by using Views extensively we just reduce the time of development but theming work increases at the same time, and when we change the views, means modifications to theme for that view(s) as well. Although it is a good CMS and powerful, robust, secured, etc, but is focused more on Developer-friendliness rather than User Friendly and Designer Friendly, etc.

I just read some stuff about Yii framework and am starting to like it, although it doesn't have so many contrib modules as Drupal does which is advantage of Drupal. I also love the way we have control in Code Igniter.

I think there should be some way to stop re-inventing the wheels in PHP, some framework that has lot of components and libraries to use from, so developers can just focus on Business rules rather then trying to figuring out how to hide labels on a form in some CMS. Anyone knows of such solution out there? Help would be appreciated.

P.S: I do not mean to say that Drupal isn't good, as I have been using it for several projects and still do, it's just that I'm looking for a faster approach in development and easier approach in theming that the design and development community can adopt.

Comment: Please do not advertise your site in your answers